# Unable to transfer 1 ether

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to write a function let user deposit 1 eth to a specific address for registering purpose.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Election {
    mapping(uint => UserRequest) public userRequest;
    // chairman account, let airline deposit to become a member
    address payable chairman;

    // Constructor
    constructor () public payable {
        chairman = msg.sender;
    }

    function register() public payable{
        chairman.transfer(1 ether);
    }
}
```

While I test the `register()` on the remix, the following error threw out.

> transact to Election.register errored: VM error: revert. revert   The
>   transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The
>   constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction
>   to get more information.

Some solution I found said I need to deploy it with a certain value, but what does that mean?

Comment: How exactly are you testing the `register` function (i.e., how do you call it and what `msg.value` do you pass to it)?

Comment: I'm asking, because it looks like you want to get the funds (ether) to be transferred from the user's account (i.e., the caller of function `register`) to your own account (i.e., the account which you have deployed your contract with). But you do this fund-transferring via the contract, i.e., the user sends to the contract and the contract sends to your account. No problem with this method so far, only, you are assuming that there is always at least 1 ether left in the contract, while this fact depends on how much the users have sent each time one of them has called the `register` function.

Comment: I am quite confused right now. What I want is there is an address called chairman who can gather all member register fee(which is 1 Ether). How I test: I deploy it with `account A`, switch the account to `account B`, and then click `register` on the remix IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @goodvibration, it's probably trying to transfer `1 ether` to the chairman, regardless of the amount the user sent to the contract when calling `register`.

If an user needs to send at least `1 ether` everytime he calls this function, and you want to be sure of it, you can add a `require` statement and check the `msg.value`, like that :

```js
    function register() public payable{
        require(msg.value >= 1 ether);
        chairman.transfer(1 ether);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the contract can have ETH as well.